# $D_E(x)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{m(E\cap(x-r,x+r))}{2r}$. Then $D_E(x)=1$ a.e. for $x\in E$ and $D_E(x)=0$ a.e. for $x\in E^c$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $E$ be Borel measurable.  Define $D_E(x)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{m(E\cap(x-r,x+r))}{2r}$.  Then $D_E(x)=1$ a.e. for $x\in E$ and $D_E(x)=0$ a.e. for $x\in E^c$.

Here is what I have tried:

**Part 1**:  To show $D_E(x)=0$ a.e. on $E^c$ I tried showing $\int_{E^c} D_E(x)=0$.

Proof: Since $E$ is measurable, $2r=m(E\cap(x-r,x+r))+m(E^c\cap(x-r,x+r))$.

\begin{align*}
\int_{E^c} D_E(x)dx &= \int_{E^c} \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{2r-m(E^c\cap(x-r,x+r))}{2r}dx\\
          &=\int_{E^c} 1 dx-\int_{E^c}\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{m(E^c\cap(x-r,x+r))}{2r}dx\\
   &= m(E^c)-\int_{E^c} D_{E^c}(x)dx
\end{align*}  I know $D_{E^c}(x)\leq 1$ and I want to show $\int_{E^c} D_{E^c}(x)dx=m(E^c)$, but I don't see it.  Is this the right approach?

**Part 2**:  To show $D_E(x)=1$ a.e. on $E$, I let $F=\{x\in E: D_E(x)<1\}$ and I want to show $m(F)=0$.  Then since $D_E(x)=1$ on $E\setminus F$,
\begin{align*}
\int_E D_E(x)dx&=\int_F D_E(x)dx+\int_{E\setminus F} D_E(x)dx\\
&= \int_F D_E(x)dx+m(E\setminus F)
\end{align*} and here I'm stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a very basic theorem in Measure Theory and a proof can be found in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: Google "Lebesgue density". Incidentally, the restriction to Borel sets is rather artificial. The result holds for arbitrary Lebesgue measurable sets (and even all non-measurable sets if the part about the complement is omitted), and I'm not aware of any proofs that become simpler when one assumes "Borel measurable" instead of "Lebesgue measurable".

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks!